# Ruby regular expression search

Tags: sql, ruby, regex, sqlite

I have such a string:

```
select count(*) from infos where pk1 = 'Information' and (pk3 = 'USA' or pk3 = 'Afrika') and value_string = 'book';
```

It is an SQL-statement and I have to find values for pk1, pk3 and value_string from the given statement as they can vary from statement to statement. (in this example I want to find the value for pk1, which is 'Information', for pk3s, which are 'Afrika' and 'USA')

My idea was to use regex such as `(pk1|pk3|value_string)((\W)*|(\d)*)(\w)*`  .

As a statement will be entered by user, it can be of different forms as "...pk1='Information' " or "...pk1= 'Information'" and so on.

I am not quite satisfied with my regex and it would be very helpful to hear another suggestions.

Thanks in advance

PS: sqlite3 sql

Comment: did you want to find the value of value string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(?:pk(?:1|3)|value_string) = '([^']+)'
```

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/z9Xbb04pCu)

Comment: Is it possible to identify if the match data belonged to pk1,pk3 or value_string?

Comment: Instead of just posting code try and explain what the code is doing for both the benefit of the OP and also future readers of your answer.